# ¿Por qué cuando digo "Él no va a ningún lado" siento que está mal dicho?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, negación

En muchas, muchas, muchas ocasiones he usado este término. Y lo he escuchado de muchas personas también, la pregunta no es si está bien dicho, sino porque siento que carece de lógica y que significa todo lo contrario.

Soy programador y lo veo así:

```
1. Él
2. No [va a] # Niego que vaya a un sitio
3. Ningún [lado] # Niego un lugar
- Él NO(Ir) a NO(lugar)
```

Si asumimos que Afirmación es `>= 1` y Negación es `0`, entonces podríamos decir que:

```
Él no va a ningún lado
  |0    |  0
  +-----+
  1
```

Estoy afirmando una negación y luego negándola.

Si dijera: Él no va a casa, solo estaría afirmando una negación `(no [va])`, que es una negación.

Creo que esto se relaciona con la frase: `En ningún momento`, al hacer algo en *ningún momento* quiero decir que no hice nada*, pero si ***No** hago algo en ningún momento* significaría que hice algo.

* Arriba escribí: *no hice nada* que cae dentro del mismo ejemplo.

Comment: He aquí una diferencia gramatical entre el español y otros idiomas. En inglés, por ejemplo, la doble negación se considera un vulgarismo; en español, en cambio, es la forma correcta de expresarse.

Comment: En ruso también. Uno dice  ["no entiendo nada" “ничего не понимaю”](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/why-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BCa%D1%8E-isnt-%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BCa%D1%8E-enough) (perdonen la liga a mi pregunta). El interesado en la parte lógica de los idiomas podría encontrar interesante la segunda *respuesta* dada ahí.

Comment: @c.p. Si, es el mundillo donde estoy, dónde las reglas matemáticas son solo sobrescritas en ciertas ocasiones por las lógicas. Toda la vida pensando que este era una de las incongruencias del español, pero al menos está documentado. Me parece interesante que en el inglés se use la doble negación boleana, `He didn't go nowhere` sí sería algo incorrecto.

Comment: No sería incorrecto sino que sería un doble negativo.  `I'm not going nowhere` significaría que sí voy a ir por otra parte del espacio-tiempo.

Comment: Me parece que si sientes eso no es tu idioma nativo....Es puríssimo español.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que he leído en la información que provee la RAE, las reglas matemáticas no tienen validez a la hora de determinar el sentido (afirmativo o negativo) de un enunciado. La clave de tu duda es que lo estás tratando de validar desde el sentido matemático.

En [Doble negación: no vino nadie, no hice nada, no tengo ninguna](http://www.rae.es/consultas/doble-negacion-no-vino-nadie-no-hice-nada-no-tengo-ninguna), la RAE especifica que la doble negación en un enunciado sirve sólo para reforzar la negación general del mismo, es decir, utilizar el adverbio *no* antes de otra negación sirve exclusivamente para enfatizar ésta última.
Siguiendo con el ejemplo que propones y acorde a las aclaraciones que provee la RAE, tenemos que:

> Él no va a ningún lado.

Es el equivalente directo de:

> A ningún lado va él.

Cito textualmente las aclaraciones de la RAE para la regla general de estos enunciados:

> La concurrencia de esas dos «negaciones» no anula el sentido negativo
>   del enunciado, sino que lo refuerza.

Comment: Nice! Ya lo veo claramente ahora, ignoraba esa regla, _no diré nada más entonces_. =D Mil gracias

Comment: Yo añadiría a esta respuesta que no se dice "Él va a ningún lado" y que "A ningún lado va él" es el tipo de expresión que uno encontraría solamante en un poema.

Comment: @Nico si pero él puso "Él **no** va a ningún lado" =D. Por otro lado la poesía es un recurso bastante útil para encontrarse con peculiaridades de uso del idioma, tengo una versión del 1992 de la traducción del francés al español de _Las flores del mal_ que tiene cualquier cantidad de palabras que nunca había leído siquiera =D y de usos totalmente artísticos lingüisticamente hablando.

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx la intención de mi sugerencia es para prevenir el uso incorrecto `él va a ningún lado`. Tu respuesta podría leerse como que la doble negación es una simple enfatización y que sería posible quitar el `no`.

Comment: @Nico Ahhh ya entiendo tu punto claramente. Y además es difícil encontrar un sustituto común a esta frase.

Comment: No es lo mismo con/sin la doble negación: «Él no va a ningún lado» afirma que «el permanecerá donde está ahora». Normalmente se usa para garantizarle tal cosa al interlocutor, de ahí el refuerzo. En cambio «Él va a ningún lado», al margen de ser una expresión inusual (¿porqué incorrecta?) significaría que sí se está moviendo o haciendo algo, pero en la dirección equivocada o  sin tener clara la dirección/objetivo/rumbo, de forma que seguramente no llegará a buen puerto, o no obtendrá ningún resultado útil de esa acción.

Comment: @Fran, En el diccionario de la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=ninguno) se explica (en el punto 4) que "cuando el sustantivo al que modifica ninguno va pospuesto al verbo, este va necesariamente en forma negativa"

Comment: @Nico, Tienes razón. La verdad es no puedo recordar un solo caso real de alguien saltándose la negación preverbal con ninguno, pero al alterar el  significado, no me pareció disparatado como recurso literario.

Answer (score 0):

La frase que usa la doble negación, se produce correctamente al responder negativamente, a algo que si debía ocurrir o esperábamos que ocurriera, reforzando la acción.

Por ejemplo,
1.-¿Cómo vas con el trabajo? ...Ya terminaron!!!
R: No, esto no va para ningún lado patrón.

2.-¿Señorita, vino el cliente? No!, no ha venido nadie Señor.

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].