# ¿"No existe nadie" o "no existe alguien"?

Tags: gramática

¿Es correcto decir "No existe nadie"? Por ejemplo: "No existe nadie que haya aprobado el examen". ¿Lo correcto sería "No existe alguien que haya aprobado el examen"?

Comment: La doble negación es completamente válida en español. Quizá la siguiente pregunta puede resolver tu duda: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5152/1978

Comment: Me sorprende que nadie haya mencionado que es más común usar el verbo haber: "No hay nadie que haya aprobado el examen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No existe nadie."

In Spanish, once you use a negative in a sentence, everything else must also be negative in that sentence. This is different from English, since it does not allow double negatives, while in Spanish, double negatives are required.

Comment: Poetically related http://www.me.gov.ar/efeme/diatango/soledad.html

Comment: Strictly speaking, Spanish has the "double negatives"; though they're different to what you are referring to. In my mother-tongue(German), we would plainly say "existe nadie". Adding "no" (i.e. no existe nadie) again would reverse the meaning. In that sense, Spanish clearly has a "double negative".

Answer (score 2):

Think in this:

```
¿Existe ALGUIEN que haya aprobado el examen?

No, no existe NADIE (que haya aprobado el examen)
```

When you use a positive sentence you can use **alguien**, but when you are using a negative one you must use **nadie**

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto decir "No existe nadie". La doble negación en español es una forma de enfatizar lo que se intenta comunicar.

Answer (score 0):

Ambas son correctas gramaticalmente, depende del contexto y el uso que quieras hacer de ellas una es más correcta que la otra.

Por ejemplo “no existe nadie” o “no existe alguien” podrían usarse en preguntas indirectas. Con la diferencia entre ellas que la doble negación enfatiza lo comunicado.

Answer (score 0):

Ambas son correctas. Sin embargo el uso es distinto. En el caso de, "No existe nadie que haya aprobado el examen" es una afirmación sobre un evento que ha ocurrido en repetidas ocasiones. Por ejemplo si estas en la universidad y tienes un profesor que nunca pone un puntaje perfecto puedes decir "**No existe nadie que haya aprobado el examen** con un puntaje perfecto". De esta manera estás asegurando que no hay nadie que lo haya hecho anteriormente.

En cuanto a "No existe alguien que haya aprobado el examen" es más común verlo en forma de pregunta dado que implícitamente se espera saber quien es ese alguien que ha aprobado el examen.

Answer (score -1):

Lo correcto sería decir "No existe nadie que haya aprobado el examen".