# Expressing a negative idea

Tags: gramática, negación

Is this phrase correct?

```
Os han castigado una vez. Veo que habéis aprendido nada.
```

To me it seems wrong, because the subjects didn't learn anything, so it seems the second phrase should be

```
Veo que no habéis aprendido nada.
```

Maybe I am mixing up portuguese and spanish.

Comment: In the meantime, [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5153/6915) to another similar question may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es correcto lo que planteás, la frase "Veo que habéis aprendido nada" no es válida al menos en el lenguaje estandarizado. Frente a este tipo de situaciones la regla más efectiva consiste en recordar cómo es la *concordancia* para las negaciones:

-Para introducir una cláusula de negación es necesario sí o sí anteponer al verbo algún adverbio negativo.

-Si la palabra **no** está al comienzo de la cláusula, entonces la misma es una negación. En tal caso, si tras el verbo se requiere algún adverbio entonces este también deberá concordar con el *no* anterior—es un adverbio de tipo negativo, pero en la cláusula no hay una doble negación.

-Si la cláusula comienza con algún otro adverbio negativo (**ni**, **nunca**, **nada**, **nadie**, **ningún(a/o)**, etc.), el mismo también indica negación, pero en este caso la concordancia se consigue sin introducir el *no*—aunque, si la circunstancia lo requiere, se precisarán más adverbios negativos como en el caso de "Nadie hizo nada".

Así, las formas correctas de re-escribir esa frase son:

> Veo que **no** habéis aprendido **nada**.

> Veo que **nada** habéis aprendido.

Si no me equivoco la primera frase es preferida por la mayoría de los hablantes. Y son incorrectas:

> *Veo que habéis aprendido nada.

> *Veo que nada no habéis aprendido.

> *Veo que no habéis aprendido algo.

Por supuesto que "Veo que no habéis aprendido todo" es válida pero en este caso se necesita usar el *todo* porque la negación es diferente—estás dando a entender que algo han aprendido.

Te recomiendo [este video de Linguriosa](https://youtu.be/h2biaeeYyIE)—en el que me basé para darte la respuesta—donde está explicado el asunto en cuestión.

Answer (score 1):

You're completely right. The first sentence is incorrect. Your correction is fine.

Spanish, like Portuguese, uses a double negation in these cases, so we say 'no tengo nada' for 'I have nothing' rather than *'tengo nada'.

As the other answer mentions, there is an exception to this general rule when the natural word order is inverted for emphasis and a negative word other than 'no' comes first. So, you can also say 'nada habéis aprendido' or 'nada tengo' or 'nunca vino' (instead of 'no vino nunca') but that is much less common.

Comment: un detalle: es más correcto hablar de 'concordancia con adverbio negativo' en vez de una 'doble negación'